# jboss 5.x disable JSESSIONID parameter. Allow only cookies

Tags: jboss5.x, jsessionid

Does anyone know whether and how is it possible to disable the JSESSIONID in jBoss 5.x from url parameters? I want to use only cookies. Please note that I'm searching for a jboss configuration or something like that. No java filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the only solution is putting url filters in the application

Comment: I can't understand why some would downvote an answer that is the only solution for jboss 5.x ...  If you find a better solution, then downvote.